# How to add GTKmm to Devhelp?

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome, gtkmm

As you know, [Devhelp](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Devhelp) is an API documentation browser for GTK+ and GNOME.
It by default have included reference for many GTK+ related libraries but it doesn't have [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/), the C++ wrapper for GTK+, which has an [online reference in gnome official reference website](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/).

I need to get an offline reference for Gtkmm so I can keep studying while not online. I read in the description of Murrayc web page that this can be added somehow, but that link and webpage seem to dead long ago.

So,is there a way to add this official library reference to my Devhelp app?

Comment: What OS and distribution are you using?

Comment: I use Deepin, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try installing package `libgtkmm-3.0-doc` (`libgtkmm-2.4-doc` if for whatever reason you still need GTK+ 2).

Comment: Thank you, that worked... you should put that as answer.
BTW, where can I find the name of these libraries in case another is required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ubuntu, documentation is separate from normal packages (both because of space and because of [licensing](https://www.debian.org/vote/2006/vote_001)). As such, you will need to install separate packages to get gtkmm's documentation:

- `libgtkmm-3.0-doc` for gtkmm for GTK+ 3
- `libgtkmm-2.4-doc` for gtkmm for GTK+ 2

There are a number of ways you can find these packages. If you know the name of the library, you can do `sudo apt-get install libname` on the command line and press Tab a few times to try to tab-complete the package name. You should see one with `-doc` at the end. You can also use a package management tool like Synaptic to find relevant packages.

The same rules apply to header files and linker libraries; substitute `-doc` with `-dev`.