# How to hide an image in a Gtk::Button

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I've inherited a code that does this:

```cpp
if (ok){
    m_Test_Button.set_image(m_Image_OK);
    m_Test_Button.set_image_position(Gtk::POS_RIGHT);
    m_Test_Button.set_always_show_image(true);
}else{
    m_Test_Button.set_image(m_Image_not_OK);
    m_Test_Button.set_image_position(Gtk::POS_RIGHT);
    m_Test_Button.set_always_show_image(true);
}
```

At certain points, the previous programmer who wrote that code attempted to use `m_Test_Button.set_always_show_image(false);` to hide the image. However, that does not really work to hide the image; it remains visible when it should stop being visible, which is a potential cause of confusion for users when changing parameters because the previous test's status prior to the change still remains visible.

I guess I can hide it just by using a blank image in its place, but there are reasons not to do it (like alignment considerations, and the fact that it looks like a kludge rather than a solution).

The `Gtk::Button` [help](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Button.html) does not even mention `set_always_show_image()` or almost anything at all related to images (other than an icon path). The only documentation I've found online seems to indicate that as the name implies, this function might not hide the image.

So I'm in the blue as for what to do to properly hide the image. I've no previous experience with Gtkmm.

**Update**: The underlying problem was that, partly due to my inexperience with Gtkmm, I was checking the docs for a different version of Gtkmm to the one I was using. Thanks to the commenters for making me aware of this.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1Button.html#ac49972018a8ed3392e897cdf9da66391) : "The image can be unset by assigning `nullptr` to `property_image()`." Did you try that?

Comment: I'm assuming Gtkmm3 because of `set_image`, which seems to no longer exist. May be you could add this to your tags to clarify.

Comment: @BobMorane No I didn't. That solves it so if you want to write it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. See also my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set_always_show_image()` seems to force the button to show the image, even if, by default, Gtkmm would have hidden it (because it would look weird, for example). According to [the docs](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1Button.html#ac49972018a8ed3392e897cdf9da66391):

> The image can be unset by assigning `nullptr` to `property_image()`.

As far as documentations goes, I have had the same problem with versions as you in the past. You can look at [this page](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/), which will contain the API documentation for all versions. You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248858/where-can-i-find-good-documentation-for-gtkmm), in which I provide a couple different ways to find information on Gtkmm I have found over the years.